# Inserting information from a cell into code

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have been working on a spreadsheet where I want a VBA code to open a document, now this document could be either a word or excel document, but I want the code to use the information from a cell.

[image]

```
Function FnPrint()
  Dim objWord
  Dim objDoc
  
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("Y:\Master Documents\Sheet & Cut\W19-316 Allergen cleandown S&C line.docx")

  objWord.Visible = True
  objDoc.PrintOut
  objWord.Quit
End Function
```

That is the code that I have, Now where it says `"Y:\Master Documents\Sheet & Cut\W19-316 Allergen cleandown S&C line.docx"`, I want that to actually change depending on a certain cell, which you can see in the above image. This is because that cell changes depending on the variables entered in the other boxes.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try: `objWord.Documents.Open(Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("O18").Value)`
Just replace the sheet name with your one.

Comment: This worked perfectly for selecting the cell range, thank you very much, Unfortunately it still only opens word documents so far, Although I am sure that's an error with my side of the code and not yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..to open a document, now this document could be either a **word or excel document**

**Logic:**

Check the file extension of the file path in the cell and then decide whether you want to open Excel or Word.

**Code (Untested):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rngDocInfo As Range
    Dim objApp As Object, objDoc As Object
    Dim myPath As String

    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet and cell which has the path        
    Set rngDocInfo = Sheet1.Range("O18")
    myPath = UCase(rngDocInfo.Value2)

    If Len(Dir(myPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid filename. File does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Get file extension and check if it is an Excel document
    If Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, ".")) Like "XLS*" Then
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set objDoc = objApp.Workbooks.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)
        objApp.Visible = True
        
        '
        ' Rest of the code
        '
    '~~> Get file extension and check if it is a Word document
    ElseIf Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, ".")) Like "DOC*" Then
        Set objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)
        objApp.Visible = True
        
        '
        ' Rest of the code
        '
    Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Document type"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**: I am not handling Text/Csv Files in the above code. If you can have those file types then amend the above code accordingly.

Comment: I attempted to run this code but got an error upon reaching                                              
```Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)```                                            in the Word.Application part.

Comment: What is the value of `rngDocInfo.Value2` Can you step through it can find out?

Comment: After stepping into the debug, It just stated "ObjDoc = Nothing"

Comment: No no... Put a break point on the line `Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(rngDocInfo.Value2)` and then check what is the value of 
 `rngDocInfo.Value2`. Alternatively you can add a `msgbox rngDocInfo.Value2` before that line and see what is the value. Does it hold a valid file path? If not then you must not have the line `Set rngDocInfo = Sheet1.Range("O18")` correct. Is it the correct Sheet? Correct Cell?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes it does hold a valid file path, it leads to the correct filepath "ms-word:ofe"|u|http:genericfilepath.com/companyname/

Comment: What does `msgbox rngDocInfo.Value2` show you?

Comment: ms-word:ofe|u|http://sword.companyname.com/AchieverPlus/DocService/98b948ca1e8aaf8aeb4427905241b2e6237/1134467/677/106007/W19-313 Dough Scaling Weights.docx   (Ihave omitted the company name at the start)

Comment: That is an invalid path... You should have something lile `"Y:\Master Documents\Sheet & Cut\.....` as shown in your screenshot. Wait, I am adding a small check to the code above.

Comment: I added a small code which will check if the file exists or not. Try now. What happens? Yo umay have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: So i tried it, and now i am receiving a different error code on this line near start  
  ```myPath = UCase(rngDocInfo.Value2)``` the error code is "Error 2023". Thank you for your time and patience btw.

Comment: I also noticed that the cell was somehow returning a link from a different part of the spreadsheet, so i went ahead and fixed that. although the error code is still the same.

Comment: If the formula retruns say a #N/A or other error then you will get the type mismatch error. Use IFERROR with the formula

Comment: The formula is not returning an error, although I will add an iferror anyway.

Comment: If it is still not working then can you share the file? I would like to check it myself? If yes then you can lod the file in wikisend.com or dropbox or any other free file sharing site and then share the link here.

Comment: There you are, here is the link: https://deanhewitt.wetransfer.com/downloads/db4bb02fa90673a391c4889795c49e3120210102161702/089e88

Comment: I saw the file. It doesn't have a sheet1... change `Set rngDocInfo = Sheet1.Range("O18")` to `Set rngDocInfo = Sheet5.Range("O18")` and try again

Comment: Ah yes, you are entirely correct, that was indeed the issue.. Thank you for your help, you have been irreplaceable.

Comment: Glad to be of help.